# better visulization of json string

Tags: php, json

I am getting table data as json response. But response looks messed up.

```
[{"0":"8","sno":"8","1":"chennai","city":"chennai","2":"active","status":"active"},{"0":"9","sno":"9","1":"kolkatta","city":"kolkatta","2":"active","status":"active"},{"0":"10","sno":"10","1":"bangalore","city":"bangalore","2":"active","status":"active"},{"0":"11","sno":"11","1":"ahmedabad","city":"ahmedabad","2":"active","status":"active"},{"0":"12","sno":"12","1":"hyderabad","city":"hyderabad","2":"active","status":"active"},{"0":"13","sno":"13","1":"delhi","city":"delhi","2":"active","status":"active"}]
```

Can be display it in better way?

php code:

```
function getcity($getcity)
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'safari');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        return;
    }   
    $today = date("Ymd");           
    $result1 = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sno,city,status from tbl_demo");
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($result1,$row);
    }
    echo  $result1 = json_encode($result1,true);  

}
```

Is it possible to show like this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: "Looks messed up" -- in what way. Be precise. The data looks wrong? It's ugly to look at? What?

Comment: Why do you care what it looks like? JSON is meant to be read by machines, not people.  If you are debugging and want to see a better representation, you could try to use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option for `json_encode()`, or paste your value into JSONlint to see it prettified, but for machine usage, there is no reason to introduce the extra whitespace.

Comment: Just a side-note, but ***never*** use the `@` operator.  You need to be checking for and fixing errors instead of blindly ignoring them.

Comment: What do you want to show that way and where?  Where are a-e and 1-5 coming from?  I don't understand the problem here and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns an array with numeric and string keys so you have the data twice (once with a numeric index and once with a string index).  Try:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Or:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you are talking about actually how it "looks" then view the PHP array. Why does the JSON need to "look" a certain way?

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($result1); ?>
</pre>
```

Or:

```
<pre>
<?php var_export($result1); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a JSON plugin for your browser.

You are encoding it using `json_encode`, so you probably just want to see it in the browser in a way you can understand it.

Comment: Yes, but he would also probably need to pass `application/json` content-type header to get the browser to display properly.  If the intent is for this value to the response to an API call, the OP should be doing this anyway.

Comment: if this is only for debugging purposes, you can use `var_dump($result1)`. function `getcity` should probably return the array instead of outputting it. It all depends on what you do with the result